# How to add vertical line in bar chart using chartJs and ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

How to insert a vertical line at specified index on x-axis.

Suppose I have 3 datasets, I want to add a vertical line to separate 1st dataset from 2nd and 3rd datasets.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good example [here](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#LineChart).

Just check out the annotation in the lineChartOptions.

I am kinda new to stackoverflow, but you should tell us what you've tried to solve the problem yourself.